# How to count the number of checked elements and the number of total elements in a to-do-list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my task:

Every time you update a task (check it,
uncheck it or add it) the output element should be updated with the number of completed
tasks and the number of tasks. E.g. if you have 7 tasks and 3 are completed, it should read
'3/7 completed'.

On part 3 of the Js code, i made an array that contained all the task elements in the HTML list created by the user input. On part 5 at the bottom, i made function called taskAmount where i attempted to use some JavaScript functions to find the number of checked boxes and the number of elements in the to-do-list. I then tried to return those values and print them out to the console to check if it worked. In the end i want to try to create an output similar to the one shown in the example, but i think i can do that by myself once i get the values i want first.

I don't get an error, but my function doesn't seem to work. My guess is that i made a mistake in the past couple of lines in the taskAmount function.

My attempt:

```js
tasks = [];

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    var ullist = document.getElementById("list");
    ullist.insertBefore(li, ullist.childNodes[0]);
  }


  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
});


// Part 4
function ifChecked() {
  var list1 = document.querySelector('ul');
  list1.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      ev.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
  }, false);
}
ifChecked();

// Part 5
function taskAmount() {
  var totalTasks;
  var checkedTasks;

  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var totalTasks = tasks.length;
    var checkedTasks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

    return (totalTasks);
    return (checkedTasks);
  })
  console.log(totalTasks);
  console.log(checkedTasks);
}
taskAmount();
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #55D;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> To do list </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1> To do list </h1>

  <form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
      <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
      <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
      <output name="result"> </output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <h2>List of things to do</h2>

  <ul id="list">
  </ul>


  <script src="todo.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two returns in the same function. Execution will stop after the first one, `return (totalTasks)` and will never reach the second return.

Comment: I want to count the number of tasks that are checked though. Wouldn't what you wrote return a true or false value? Not sure if i understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yeah, i thought that could be the reason. I thought i recalled from Python that you can't have more than two returns in the same function, but you can still return several values, right? Like this: return(totalTasks, checkedTasks)?

Comment: One problem you have is that your function `addTask()` creates an element with id `box`. If you run that function twice or more then you have duplicated id's which is not allowed in html.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only return one. However, you can return an object or an array that contains multiple values. I;e, `{tasks: 10, completeTasks: 5}`

Comment: Didn't think about that Mark, thanks. I'll change it to class. Nonetheless, i don't think that's the problem. Ok Lewis, i'll try it

Comment: @HankMoody No the id's are not the cause of your problem, but can be the cause of future problems. That's why I commented it instead of posting an answer. Changing it to class is a valid way to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, glad you noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the event handler inside the taskAmount() function and call the function from add tasks fixes the issue. Also made your id unique for the generated content.

```js
tasks = [];
var idCount = 1;

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  cbox.addEventListener('change', taskAmount);
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box' + idCount);
  idCount++;
  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    var ullist = document.getElementById("list");
    ullist.insertBefore(li, ullist.childNodes[0]);
  }


  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
  taskAmount();
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
});


// Part 4
function ifChecked() {
  var list1 = document.querySelector('ul');
  list1.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      ev.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
  }, false);
}
ifChecked();

// Part 5
function taskAmount() {  
  var totalTasks = tasks.length;
  var checkedTasks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

  console.log(totalTasks);
  console.log(checkedTasks);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #55D;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> To do list </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1> To do list </h1>

  <form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
      <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
      <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
      <output name="result"> </output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <h2>List of things to do</h2>

  <ul id="list">
  </ul>


  <script src="todo.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it updates the number of elements, but not the checked tasks number though.

Comment: Never mind, i forgot to check the boxes. Still, they only update after i submit, so it doesn't register that you have checked boxes until you add a new list element. How do i fix that? I'm thinking about adding an onchange function to the checkbox

Comment: @HankMoody You can add the function `taskAmount()` to be used as an event handler for either the `onchange` or `oninput` events on the checkbox. Then they will update when checked. Note that you need to add the event handler to the checkbox each time you add a new one, or use event delegation.

Comment: Updated my answer by adding the event handler to the checkbox whenever one is created. (`cbox.addEventListener('change', taskAmount);`);

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: @HankMoody, If this answers your question please mark this a accepted answer. Other people can see this question is already answered. If one of the other answers is better for you accept that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

totalTasks and checkedTasks are not defined outside the function.  I updated the code to make checkedTasks update when you click

```js
tasks = [];

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    var ullist = document.getElementById("list");
    ullist.insertBefore(li, ullist.childNodes[0]);
  }


  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);
  //console.log(tasks);
  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
});


// Part 4
function ifChecked() {
  var list1 = document.querySelector('ul');
  
  list1.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      ev.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
      
      var checkedTasks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
      console.log(checkedTasks);
      
    }
  }, false);
  
  
  
}
ifChecked();

// Part 5
function taskAmount() {
  var totalTasks;
  var checkedTasks;

  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var totalTasks = tasks.length;
   // console.log(totalTasks)
    var checkedTasks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    console.log(totalTasks);
 // console.log(checkedTasks);
    return (totalTasks);
    return (checkedTasks);
    
  })
 // console.log(totalTasks);
 // console.log(checkedTasks);
}
taskAmount();
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #55D;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> To do list </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1> To do list </h1>

  <form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
      <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
      <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
      <output name="result"> </output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <h2>List of things to do</h2>

  <ul id="list">
  </ul>


  <script src="todo.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works, but not for the checkbox counter.

Comment: it works for the checkbox counter too but maybe not they way you want.  add a second item and you'll see the count update

Comment: I updated the code to make checkTasks update when you check or uncheck the box

Answer (score 1):

I returned an object from your taskAmount() function and rendered it into the html after hitting submit. I also got rid of your second submit event handler.

```js
tasks = [];
tasklist = [];
var checked = 0; 
var total = 0; 
  
function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");


  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    var ullist = document.getElementById("list");
    ullist.insertBefore(li, ullist.childNodes[0]);
  }


  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}




// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById("finished_tasks").innerHTML = taskAmount().checked + "/" +      taskAmount().total;
});


// Part 4
  var list1 = document.querySelector('ul');
  var finished = document.getElementById("finished_tasks"); 
  list1.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   
    if(ev.target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
     ev.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
      document.getElementById("finished_tasks").innerHTML = taskAmount().checked + "/" +           taskAmount().total;
    }
  }, false);



// Part 5
function taskAmount() {
  var totalTasks;
  var checkedTasks;

  var totalTasks = tasks.length;
  var checkedTasks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  tasklist = ({
    checked: checkedTasks,
    total: totalTasks
  });

  return tasklist;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #55D;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> To do list </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1> To do list </h1>

  <form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
      <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
      <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
      <output name="result"> </output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <h2>List of things to do</h2>

  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
  <div id="finished_tasks"></div>


  <script src="todo.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice! Checkbox counter doesn't update though, but i think i know what to do now.

Comment: right now, the update of the counter is based on the submit event, not the event of a checkbox being changed.

Comment: there you go. One small change and you're in business.

Comment: Thanks! If i may ask, why do you have this twice: document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = taskAmount().checked + "/" +      taskAmount().total;

Comment: I see that it doesn't work without it, but i don't understand why you need both

Comment: You don't technically need both. If you want, you could rewrite it the line in the submit event handler as, document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 0 "/" + tasks.length; The reason I have it twice in my code is once for the initial submit and setting it again when checking or unchecking a check box because it updates the completed task .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182525/discussion-between-perrinprograms-and-hank-moody).

Answer (score 0):

Well there are more thing in your code that are strange. First of all, you have defined variables totalTasks and checkedTasks in the scope of taskAmount function, but than you have redefined them in the click handler function. Keyword var shouldnt be there if you want to keep the values in the whole taskAmount function.

Also only first return from the click handler function will be executed, but that doesnt really matter since you don't use the returned value anyway.

So try it like this:

```
function taskAmount() {
  var totalTasks;
  var checkedTasks;

  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function() {
    totalTasks = tasks.length;
    checkedTasks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  })
  console.log(totalTasks);
  console.log(checkedTasks);
}
```